# Where can I get a full list of wordpress errors in plain text?

Tags: errors

When a wordpress error pops up, it's in the code, now I can find scattered errors tutorials all over the internet, but is there specific list somewhere?

Like:

- error x
- syntax error y

etc...

Something clean in plain text I want to explore every possible wordpress errors, learn them and offer repair services.

Comment: The vast majority of errors come from PHP, not WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Enable [debug logging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log) in `wp-config.php`:

```php
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); // Enable debugging

// Default logging path is wp-content/debug.log
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true /* or custom path e.g. '/path/to/debug.log' */ );

define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true /* or false if you want to just log the errors */ );
```

That will capture and store all errors (either from core PHP, or generated by WordPress).